# Catching the "dropping" bit value

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

**What am I looking for?**

Let's consider `int a = 5` for example

Its binary is : `101`

So when we do

```
a >> 1
```

then the rightmost bit, i.e., 1 in this case, would *drop off*, I want to catch it in some variable..i.e.,

```
1st iteration k = 1 
2nd iteration k = 0 
3rd iteration k = 1
```

In this case I have a hard-coded value but it can be any arbitrary user input for number.

If I do `b = a >> 1` then `b= a/2` so m clueless here!

**Why am I asking this question?**

For example, take program for conversion of decimal to binary, in that case, if I can catch the *falling bit*, then the program would be done in 3-4 lines max...

there are off course, other logic’s for which I need to know if it's possible!

Comment: **if u plan to downvote, please do drop a reason for it**, as m not a `bit` person in my daily programming life! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store the lowest bit in a variable before shifting, e.g.,

```
int a = 5;
int lowestBit = a & 1;
a >>= 1;
```

Comment: is there a similar way for left-most bit too....assuming i am not considering signed-bit??

Comment: @NoobEditor For the most significant bit just change the bitmask `1` into one that has only that bit set, e.g., `0x80000000` or `0x40000000` for 32-bit `int`s depending on whether you want to catch the sign bit or not. If the hexadecimal syntax seems hard to understand, just form the bit mask with shifts, i.e., `signBit = a & (1 << 31)`, `nextHighest = a & (1 << 30)`, keeping in mind that `(1 << 0) == 1`, i.e., the lowest bit.